# Accessing network resources with UNC, without mapping drive

Tags: c, winapi, unc

I wish to access some files over the network using a UNC path (\example.uk.com\d) which requires credentials. I know there are some WIN32 functions to acheive this I.E. WNetAddConnection2, however, I do not wish the map the drive.

Is there anyway I can achieve this? my application is in C. Thanks.

Comment: Most (all?) Win32 file system functions will happily accept a UNC path, e.g. `DWORD dwAttr = GetFileAttributes(L"\\\\server\\share\\folder\\file.ext");`

Comment: @JonathanPotter I think the OP is asking about obtaining credentials prior to accessing the file.

Comment: `WNetAddConnection2` does not force a mapping unless you want one: *... or if `lpLocalName` is NULL, the function makes a connection to the network resource without redirecting a local device.*